# How to represent things from up to down?

Tags: word-choice

If I want to represent a picture with a lot of details and I want to say that I'm going to tell about the details from the upper part to the lower part of the picture, what is the alternatives to say it?

an example: 
* I am going to represent it from above to down. (correct?) 
* I am going to represent it from up to down. (correct?)

Comment: I think it's better to say "I am going to represent (describe) the details of the picture in its descending order or I am going to represent the details of the picture from up to down".

Answer (score 3):

In a picture, *from top to bottom*.

> I am going to *talk about the picture detail* from **top to bottom**.

*represent* does not seem like the correct verb, as I understand the context, so I am going with "to tell about" as you mentioned.

Comment: That's right also when I'm going to talk about a specific part that is located in the middle of the picture? for example, If I'm going to talk about the urinary system, it begins in the kidneys that are located in the middle of the body and ends in the urethra.

Comment: ^vote with a note: To answer @Assiduous's subquestion, care to add something like "... talk about the urinary system from the kidneys downward"?